# how to show timer for each product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to show timer for each product...
Bt when I put my code in loop it only give timer to one product....
I need to show timer for each and every product in my product page...I m creating Deal of The day..
I did some work...Bt it working one product only...
I need to know that waht is the best way to give timer to every product...
Currently I m getting timer in my last product...

### My code is bellow..

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- <h3>New Products</h3> --> 
    <?php if ($this->getProducts()->getSize() > '0') { ?>

        <?php foreach ($this->getProducts() as $_Product) { ?> 

            <?php //echo $timespan = strtotime($_Product['special_to_date']) - strtotime($_Product['special_from_date']);exit; ?>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
                <div><a href="<?php echo $_Product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_Product, 'small_image')->resize(145, 200) ?>" alt="<?php echo $_Product->getName(); ?>"></a></div>
                <div align="center"><h4><?php echo $_Product->getName(); ?></h4></div>
                <div align="center"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_Product->getPrice()); ?></div>
                   <?php // echo "<pre>"; print_r($_Product->toArray());exit; ?>
                <div id="timeremaining<?php echo $_Product['sku'] ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <script>
                var target_date = new Date('<?php echo $_Product['special_to_date'] ?>').getTime();
         //alert(target_date);
                var localMinDiff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;  // get the difference between local time and GMT >> in mins >> mins to milliseconds conversion
                target_date = target_date - localMinDiff;
                var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
                var countdown = document.getElementById("timeremaining<?php echo $_Product['sku'] ?>");

                var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

                    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
                    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                    if (days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0)
                    {
                        countdown.innerHTML = '';
                        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (days > 0)
                        {
                            days = days + 'Days,';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            days = '';
                        }
                        countdown.innerHTML = '( ' + days + checkTime(hours) + ':' + checkTime(minutes) + ':' + checkTime(seconds) + ' remaining)';
                    }
                }, 1000);

                function checkTime(i) {
                    if (i < 10) {
                        i = '0' + i
                    }
                    ;
                    return i;
                }

            </script>

        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `date_diff` function in php

Answer (score 1):

To calculate date differences, you can convert the date strings to timestamps (PHP < 5.3):

```
$timespan = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate);
```

`$timespan` will then hold the number of seconds between the two dates given and you can further process the value.

For PHP >= 5.3, you can use the DateTime Object:

```
$start = new DateTime($startDate);
$end = new DateTime($endDate);
$interval = $end->diff($start);
echo $interval->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Comment: Since it is a time difference, the date function might not be the best way. It produces a formatted date which is exactly `$timespan` seconds after the UNIX epoch time. Depending on context, it might be enough to only show hours, minutes and seconds (since it's a Deal of the Day).

Comment: my bad. im doing something when i posted it haha .

Comment: so he needs to divide the result to 60 to get the minutes then another 60 to get the hours, and 24 to get the days? is there any function or shorcut for this ?